# Identify patterns in Stanford Tregex in Python

Tags: nltk, stanford-nlp

I want to identify a specific pattern when parsing a text using `StanfordNLP`, `StanfordParser` and `Tregex`. The desired output can be produced using `nltk` and `nltk.RegexpParser` as shown below:

`nltk` code:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
text = "New developments in the science of motion picture photography are not 
        abundant at this advanced stage of the game"
cp_pattern = r"""CP: {<NN|JJ|><NN|JJ>}"""
parser = nltk.RegexpParser(cp_pattern)
tree = parser.parse(pos_tag(word_tokenize(text)))
for subtree in tree.subtrees():
    if subtree.label() == 'CP':  
        print(str(subtree))
```

and the output:

```
(CP motion/NN picture/NN)
(CP advanced/JJ stage/NN)
```

Using `StanfordParser`, the following code tokenizes and parses the `text`:

```
   from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordParser    
   parse_jar = 'path to stanford parser jar'
   parse_model = 'path to stanford parser model'
   parser_st=StanfordParser(path_to_jar=parse_jar,path_to_models_jar=parse_model)
   parse_tree = list(parser_st.raw_parse(text))
   print(parse_tree)
```

Printing the `parse_tree` will give me the following output:

```
[Tree('ROOT', [Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('NNP', ['New']), Tree('NNS', ['developments'])]), Tree('PP', [Tree('IN', ['in']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['the']), Tree('NN', ['science'])]), Tree('PP', [Tree('IN', ['of']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NN', ['motion']), Tree('NN', ['picture']), Tree('NN', ['photography'])])])])])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBP', ['are']), Tree('RB', ['not']), Tree('ADJP', [Tree('JJ', ['abundant']), Tree('PP', [Tree('IN', ['at']), Tree('NP', [Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['this']), Tree('VBN', ['advanced']), Tree('NN', ['stage'])]), Tree('PP', [Tree('IN', ['of']), Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['the']), Tree('NN', ['game'])])])])])])])])])]
```

Now, I am wondering how can I define my own desired pattern `cp_pattern` in `StanfordParser` and identify it like what I do using `nltk`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Having `text`, do you want to get `['(CP motion/NN picture/NN)', '(CP advanced/JJ stage/NN)']` with just a normal `re` expression? But you should understand you still need NLTK to tokenize the string. Please clarify.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would like to extract my desired pattern from the `parse_tree`. `nltk` has this nice `nltk.RegexpParser(cp_pattern)` to define my own parser. I am looking for a way to do the same but using `StanfordParser`.